# upload image corrupted using put() on laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

my code is

```
$avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$path = request('avatar')->storeAs('avatars',$avatarName);
Storage::disk('public')->put($avatarName,$path);
```

and I did on filesystem.php

```
'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => public_path().'/avatars',
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

image is uploading. But image is corrupted. Original image file size is 1.19MB, after upload image size is 31 Bytes. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you can make sure its a file and a valid file.
Then you can use [`storeAs`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#storing-uploaded-files) :

```
if($request->hasFile('avatar') && $request->file('avatar')->isValid()){

    $avatarName = $user->id.'_avatar'.time().'.'.request('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();

    // public as the 3rd argument is the disk name to store file in
    $file->storeAs('your_path_here', $avatarName, 'public');
}
```

Comment: thanks man (y). It is working for this line $file->storeAs('your_path_here', $avatarName, 'public');